# Mac Mini - black pixels show up as purple

Tags: mac, mac-mini, hdmi, color

Has anyone encountered this problem: It's a mac mini. It's connected to a tv via a HDMI cable, both of which work fine with other computers. However, when connected to the HISENSE tv, at native resolution, all black pixels come out as purple. If I switch to scaled resolutions, the colour is fine - but of course the resolution is now off. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a problem I once saw on a DVD player with a DVI output, where it was outputting YCbCr instead of RGB.  If there is a video format menu on either device, have a look there

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see any such setting on my tv or mac mini.